# How to integrate Behat with PHPStorm / other IDE

Tags: php, ide, bdd, phpstorm, behat

[Behat](http://behat.org/) is the leading [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development) framework for PHP.  I use [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and want to integrate [Behat](http://behat.org/) into the IDE as an external tool.

**Question:** How should I set up Behat as an external tool (ie, output filters, macros, etc) in PHPStorm or any other IDE for that matter?

note: [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html) has [deprecated their BDD support](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/6aa9183496f9bb2131d17ba08195a93a07937762#comments) and will remove it in 3.6 (in deference to Behat), so I believe the integrated PHPUnit testing in PHPStorm isn't ideal for [Behavior Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development).

**update Feb 8-2012**: PHPStorm's [roadmap](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15801728) indicates Behat syntax will be integrated in the 4.0 release which is due Q1 2012! What can I say - [PHPStorm rocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692618/php-developing-suite/5074614#5074614).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, if anybody else out there needs it.

**First**, create behat-html.bat in the same folder as behat.bat (your PHP folder).  The contents of behat-html.bat should look something like this:

```
call %PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR%\behat.bat --out="features\support\behat_test_output.html" --colors --format="html" %*
call features\support\behat_test_output.html
```

**Second**, in PHPStorm setup the external tool to run Behat with whatever parameters you like (tags, scenarios, etc).  Here are my settings for a general-purpose command:

```
Program: C:\Progz\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\behat-html.bat
Parameters: $FilePath$
Working Directory: $FileDir$\..
```

**Third**, setup a Keymap to run the tool.

Now with your .feature file in focus, press your shortcut key.  The batch file will run the scenarios, generate a pretty HTML output file, and open that file with your default browser.  Not as nice as having it integrated into PHPStorm, but it's a pretty efficient work flow nevertheless.

*Tip*: You might also want to set up a second external-tool in order to run with --strict

Hope this helps!

Comment: How did you set up the formatting? BTW, the screenshot link does not work anymore.

Comment: In order to setup formatting, go into Settings|File Types and add a new file type. Give it a name and a description, and you should see a series of form inputs that allow you to define how comments are denoted, and up to 4 different types of 'Keyword'. You can then assign syntax colouring to these keywords by going into Settings|Editor|Colors & Fonts|Custom and you should see the appropriate syntax options (Keyword 1 is the colour for keywords you added in the first tab of your new file type, for example). Hope this helps!

Comment: @FireCoding : too bad, if you have a `'` in your feature description, it's interpreted as a string. This char is widely used in French. Do you know a way to limit the string detection to the `"` char ?

Comment: @ClementHerreman : I'm not 100% sure, but I believe this is built deep into the core of the IDE and its parsing algorithm... I cannot imagine that this is changeable, but you'd better ask JetBrains.  Let us know if you find a solution.